# Is it possible to sync an iPad 9 to a Windows PC without ever connecting it via cable

Tags: ipad, wifi, usb, data-synchronization

I have a new iPad 9, which seems to work ok and was supplied with a usbc to lighting cable.

I also have a ThinkPad t470s which has 1 USBC port. Lenovo sold millions of laptops with dubious USBC ports, of which the t470s is known to be affected. I have updated it with all the latest drivers and BIOS, but when I connect to latest iTunes on Windows 11, the iPad only charges, but is not recognised in device manager or in iTunes.

So it's reasonable to assume that the port is faulty, however not 100%. I could just buy a new usb-a to lightning cable or a to c adaptor and try that, however I don't particularly need a usb a cable or adaptor, so I'd rather just WiFi sync without wasting money on a cable.

Is it possible to get the iPad to WiFi sync without ever connecting with a cable?

Comment: What have you tried to get Wi-Fi sync to work between this laptop and the iPad?

Comment: I get the feeling you need to get iTunes to first see it over USB before it can be set to backup over WiFi. [I can't test as all my devices have already been 'seen' by the computer].

Comment: @MacGuffin Apple support it should be charging on the same wifi network and then will show up in itunes as a device. However it does not (charging via mains charger) I tried connecting via the (possibly faulty) usbc port, and it likewise does not appear as a device